# Trying to get JSON data from python application to google sheets

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I have a python program which outputs JSON files. I want to get the JSON files into google sheets.

I looked for a way to upload JSON files directly to google sheets, and couldn't find a way. 
This prompted me to look for a way to store my JSON files online, so google sheets could use an API to call the JSON data.

I have tried using Google Cloud Platform, but I could not find a way to call the JSON data from Google Cloud Platform to google sheets. I looked into a few other web based services that offer storage and api services at low-no cost, but I could not find any. I am fairly proficient Python, but that's the extent of my programming knowledge.

At this point, I am at a loss as far as a method of getting my JSON data into a google spreadsheet. Any and all advice/suggestions are welcome and appreciated, and I am glad to answer any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this https://pypi.org/project/tablib/0.9.3/ 
to convert if from JSON to xls. Then you can open it up directly in google sheets.

Comment: Wow! This is a really neat library. Thank you! I'm having trouble using "tablib.Databook()" to convert JSON to CSV. What parameters do I pass into "tablib.Databook()"? (seriously thank you so much this is amazing)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Found a video which shows how to write Dictionary structured data to CSV.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1XiCh-mGCA